# Jenkins Pipeline build specific branches on pull/pr

Tags: jenkins, github, automation, jenkins-pipeline

I think I'm missing something quite simple here so I thought I would ask.
I have a development branch that developers raise PR's against, when this occurs I would like my Jenkins pipeline to automatically trigger.

Then once a merge happens and a push goes to the development branch, I want to do some extra steps which I have configured in the pipeline successfully.

The problem is how do I get Jenkins to automatically checkout and build branches that have a PR raised against development?

Currently I'm using GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling and I can see the triggers in github being fired but it just constantly rebuilds the master branch instead of the branch that the PR is being raised on.

Answer (score 0):

We are using [github-branch-source](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-branch-source/) and this automatically builds PRs.
There is a nice documentation: [cloudbees docu](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-admin-guide/github-branch-source-plugin)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what I need, seems complicated and overkill for me. GitHub actions did what I required automatically so maybe I think it is simple in Jenkins but it really isn't. It seems like it should be a pretty standard setup as far as a ci-cd setup goes?